# Why does Protractor/JavaScript/Node build differently (failing) when I move code into it's own file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

I've implemented the custom processor as [seen here](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/docs/customize-output.md). I got it to work by placing it (pretty much exactly the example code there) alongside my instantiation of the jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(...) in the `onPrepare()` method in the protractor.config.js file. That's a lot of code though, so I thought I'd move it into it's own TimeProcessor class/file and reference it.

When I did that though I get `E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Processor is not a constructor` and `E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100`.  I can see that I'm getting the error from the jasmine spec reporter, but why would moving my code to a custom class cause a packaged module to fail with this error on one of it's classes?

TimeProcessor.js class

```
module.exports = function TimeProcessor(configuration) {
    var DisplayProcessor = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').DisplayProcessor;

    function getTime() {
        return '[' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS') + ']';
    }

    TimeProcessor.prototype = new DisplayProcessor();

    TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuite = function (suite, log) {
        return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
    };

    TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuccessfulSpec = function (spec, log) {
        return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
    };

    TimeProcessor.prototype.displayFailedSpec = function (spec, log) {
        return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
    };

    TimeProcessor.prototype.displayPendingSpec = function (spec, log) {
        return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
    };
};
```

protractor.config.js

```
const { TimeProcessor } = require('./e2e/common/logging/TimeProcessor.js');
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const log4js = require('log4js');
const moment = require('moment');

exports.config = {
...
  onPrepare() {
        require('jasmine-expect');
        // Following TimeProcessor code worked here! But not in it's own file
        // let moment = require('moment');
        // var DisplayProcessor = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').DisplayProcessor;
        //
        // function TimeProcessor(configuration) {
        // }
        //
        // function getTime() {
        //     return '[' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS') + ']';
        // }
        //
        // TimeProcessor.prototype = new DisplayProcessor();
        //
        // TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuite = function (suite, log) {
        //     return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        // };
        //
        // TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuccessfulSpec = function (spec, log) {
        //     return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        // };
        //
        // TimeProcessor.prototype.displayFailedSpec = function (spec, log) {
        //     return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        // };
        //
        // TimeProcessor.prototype.displayPendingSpec = function (spec, log) {
        //     return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        // };
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new SpecReporter(
                {
                    spec: {
                        displayStacktrace: true,
                        displayDuration: true
                    },
                    customProcessors: [TimeProcessor]
                }));
        browser.logger = log4js.getLogger('protractorLog4js');
        browser.logger.level = browser.params.log.level;
        // LoginLogoutWorkflow.login();
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you wrap the code of `TimeProcessor.js` within a `module.exports = { "yourCode" }`?

Comment: TimeProcessor is not exported, is it?

Comment: Okay, nope! It's not exported. When I try module.exports = { <stuff in TimeProcessor.js> } though I'm getting errors in my code. I can elaborate further if necessary. Is there an example I can try to work off of that you know of? I'm not getting things specific to this when I try googling javascript export.

Comment: I updated the TimeProcessor code and now it makes it past the constructor error and now says `Error: TypeError: processor.displaySpecStarted is not a function`. I don't have that as one of the functions I'm overrriding(?) from the DisplayProcessor Prototype. Any suggestions are appreciated!